# Every Response is used from every if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am trying to do a simple text game with C#
when i run this and type yes or anything else i get every Response like "Great!"
"Ok!'
"Aww"
and "what?"

here is my code

```
namespace HelloTutorial 
{ 
    internal class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {

            Console.Write("Username: ");

            string userName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + userName);

            Console.WriteLine(userName + ", would you like to play a game?");
            string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
            userAnswer.ToLower();
            if (userAnswer == "yes"  ) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Great!");
            }
            if (userAnswer == "sure")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
            }
            if (userAnswer == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aww");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

help me

Comment: `;` is an empty statement which does nothing, and there's no such thing as an if/if/else statement (it's two separate statements)

Comment: So what you need help with

Comment: `if (userAnswer == "yes"  ) ;` you have a trailing semicolon which closes the `if` block. The next block is _always_ executed.  It doesn't explain why you would "always" get `Aww` though.

Comment: This is not the cause of your current problem, but `ToLower()` doesn't modify that `string` instance but returns a new one, so you'd need to change that to `userAnswer = userAnswer.ToLower();`.

Comment: The "Aww" vs "What" is caused by the the fact that your if blocks are not nested, meaning they still have to be evaluated after your initial block is evaluated for "yes". But to D Stanley's point, you won't always get "Aww". You only get it when typing no from my quick testing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to nest properly those ifs, delete the semicolon of your first if condition and convert your answer to lowercases too. In this line:

```
userAnswer.ToLower();
```

You're not converting it, the correct way to do it is:

```
userAnswer=userAnswer.ToLower();
```

Then, my suggestion for your conditions would be a simple if else structure:

```
if (userAnswer == "yes") //<--- here
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Great!");
  }
else if (userAnswer == "sure")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
  }
else if (userAnswer == "no")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Aww");
  }
else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("What?");
  }
```

**Why?**
Because in your current code, its a bad code habit to have multiple ifs when you can optimize it with the if else structure, also, you have a logic error in your last "Else" cause it is linked only to the if (userAnswer == "no"). Just give it a check on how code runs.

**Edit**
I forgot the part where you had a semicolon closing your if condition, i added here too, you need to delete it.